# Inserting unicode MYSQL results within Python

Tags: python, mysql

```
 if results:
      for line in results:
           print line[0] + ' - ' + line[1]
```

I need to insert a '-' between line[0] and line[1], but when I enter the above code, I get the error message 'coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found'. Any suggestions on a way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that line[0] or line[1] holding an int number.

by using "+" and 'some string' you are telling python please append to the string the next string, but you have an int so the interpreter is raising a problem.

try to use:

if results:
      for line in results:
           print str(line[0]) + ' - ' + str(line[1])

"+" note in python will change it's "action" when meeting different data types. it's a very powerful feature but as default it cannot add different datatypes.